# Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, angular6

I have the user service for login using angular 6 is :

```
loginUser(user:any):Observable<any>{
         const headers=new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});
         return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/login",user,{headers:headers});
   } 

saveUser(user:any):Observable<any>{
         const headers=new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});
         return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/registration",user,{headers:headers});
   }
```

And i have ALL the OPTIONS enabled as permitAll in spring boot as :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests().
        antMatchers("/**").permitAll()

        .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();;

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
        httpSecurity.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().includeSubDomains(true).maxAgeInSeconds(31536000);

    }
```

When I try to login and sign up from my computer where these projects are setup then
But when i am accessing my localhost from other computer using my IP address like 192.168.1.111:8080/login then it showed me first error like :

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.111:8090' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Then i added Allowed cross origin extension in chrome and it showed me again the error like :

```
Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
```

Comment: Thanks for providing code which might help solve the problem, but generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem.